# I am having Error importing tensorflow as tf?

Tags: tensorflow, error-handling, runtime-error, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

while importing tensorflow

> Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.1'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

> 2020-08-28 00:21:19.206030: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.

system

- Hp 245 g5 notebook
- operating system ubuntu 18.4

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to use the TensorFlow-GPU version and you have downloaded conflicting software versions for it.

**Note: GPU support is available for Ubuntu and Windows with CUDA enabled cards only.**

If you have a Cuda enabled card follow the instructions provided below.

As stated in Tensorflow documentation. The software requirements are as follows.

```
Nvidia gpu drivers - 418.x or higher
Cuda - 10.1 (TensorFlow >= 2.1.0)
cuDNN - 7.6
```

Make sure you have these exact versions of the software mentioned above. See [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements)

Also, check the system requirements [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements).

For downloading the software mentioned above see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#linux_setup).

For downloading TensorFlow follow the instructions provided [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#1.-install-the-python-development-environment-on-your-system) to correctly install the necessary packages.

Comment: Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it worked.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question finally it worked for me